# Error al elegir los datos de un campo específico en una base de datos SQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema al querer acceder a los datos de una base de datos SQL correspondientes a un campo específico, utilizando la palabra clave WHERE. Cuando accedo a todos esos datos de manera completa (es decir, sin especificar los datos que quiero mostrar utilizando WHERE), la consulta se realiza correctamente, pero al momento de especificar qué campos voy a utilizar, me aparece este error:

> **Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean**

Muestro el programa creado, así como el enlace para poder descargar la tabla que utilizo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles.css">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Conexión con una base de datos mediante PHP, MySQL y un servidor web</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Conexión a una base de datos</h1>

    <?php

/* Primero definimos los cuatro datos principales que necesitamos para     
      acceder a nuestra base de datos. */

   // Definimos la dirección de nuestro servidor de base de datos.
   $db_host = "localhost";

   // Definimos el nombre de nuestra base de datos.
   $db_nombre = "pruebas";

   // Definimos el nombre de usuario de nuestra base de datos.
   $db_usuario = "root";

   // Definimos la contraseña para nuestra base de datos.
   $db_contra = ""; // Como NO tenemos contraseña, dicha variable la 
                    // igualamos a un valor vacío.
       // Incluimos los datos necesarios para poder establecer la conexión.
       include("datos_conexion.php");

       // Ahora realizamos la conexión con la base de datos.

       // Realizando la conexión mediante PROGRAMACIÓN ORIENTADA A PROCEDIMIENTOS.
       $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);

       if(mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
          echo "<p>Fallo al conectar con la base de datos.</p>";

          exit();
       }

       mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("<p>No se encuentra la base de datos.</p>");

       mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");

       // Definimos la consulta.

       // ESTA SENTENCIA FALLA AL MOMENTO DE CAMBIAR LA CONSTULTA POR:
       // SELECT * FROM productos PAÍSESORIGEN = "ESPAÑA";
       **$consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos";**

       // Ejecutamos la consulta.
       $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

       // Visualizamos los resultados. Los leemos línea por línea y los almacenamos en una
       // variable.

 for($num_filas = 0; $num_filas <= mysqli_num_rows($resultados); $num_filas++)
      {
          $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);

          for($posicion = 0; $posicion < count($fila); $posicion++)
          {
             echo "<p>" . $fila[$posicion] . "</p>";
          }

          echo "<br>";
      }

       // Al final cerramos la conexión con la base de datos.
       mysqli_close($conexion);
       ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Finalmente, [adjunto el enlace para poder descargar la tabla que estoy utilizando](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1f5qgfpjuf9arp/PRODUCTOS.ods?dl=0).

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: La consulta tiene un error de sintaxis, debes escribirla así: `SELECT * FROM productos WHERE PAÍSESORIGEN = 'ESPAÑA';` observa que omitiste la palabra `WHERE` y que el nombre del país debe ir entre comillas `'`  simples. Pero... haces una lectura muyyyy rara de tus resultados, **¿por qué los mareas tanto entre dos bucles `for`?**  ¿Qué es lo que quieres mostrar? El código se puede mejorar.

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta tiene un error de sintaxis, estás omitiendo la palabra `WHERE`y además, conviene que pongas el criterio entre comillas simples.

No obstante, veo que das demasiadas vueltas al código para leer los resultados. Propongo un código corregido, en el que:

- Se nombran de forma explícita las columnas que quieres de la tabla, aunque sean todas conviene hacerlo así. Si hay alguna columna que no necesitas la quitas del `SELECT` y en consecuencia la quitas también de la lectura de resultados.
- Usaré uno de los métodos más comunes para leer datos. Se trata de [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), el cual te crea un arreglo asociativo de los datos usando los nombres de cada columna. Con un simple  `while` se pueden leer todas las filas sin marear tanto los datos con dos bucles.  Si necesitaras los datos para transportarlos a otro sitio, este sería el método idóneo también. En vez de imprimirlos en ese caso irías guardando cada fila en un array.

Este es el código (sólo la parte de la consulta):

```
   $consulta = "SELECT 
                    CÓDIGOA,
                    SECCIÓN,
                    NOMBRE,
                    PRECIO,
                    FECHA,
                    IMPORTA,
                    PAÍSDEORIGEN,
                    FOTO
                FROM productos 
                WHERE PAÍSESORIGEN = 'ESPAÑA'";

   // Ejecutamos la consulta.
   $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

/*Leemos e imprimimos cada fila con sus columnas */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {
    printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $row["CÓDIGOA"], $row["SECCIÓN"],$row["NOMBRE"],$row["PRECIO"],$row["FECHA"],$row["IMPORTA"],$row["PAÍSDEORIGEN"],$row["FOTO"]);
}

 /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
mysqli_free_result($resultados);

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

---

#### Otras recomendaciones

Evita el uso de `Ñ` y de acentos para nombrar las columnas de tu tabla. Te podría traer problemas en contextos en que olvides manejar adecuadamente la codificación.